# Wordpress showing install screen after max_questions error

Tags: database, installation, errors

I am working in a PHO environment in Heroku with ClearDB. At some point (really low), I get this error:

`WordPress database error User 'XX' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 3600) for query SHOW TABLES LIKE 'wp\\_users' made by display_setup_form`.

I guess this is an error due to use the free database plan of ClearDB. However, after getting that error (spotted in the server logs), the server is redirecting to the install screen.

Is there any way to catch that error, and avoid showing the install screen?

Comment: you're correct, its the max queries per hour provided by your host. It resets after one hour. Maybe you can contact your hosting support for better guidance on this

Comment: I have been getting this error alot recently as well. No real insights other yet. Did you get it resolved?

Comment: Basically I moved from ClearDB to Amazon RDS, where that limit is not imposed.

I found clearDB on Heroku as a non viable DB for Wordpress. If you want to keep with ClearDB, I would choose one of their AWS single tenant services, where you don't have that limitation either.

http://w2.cleardb.net/aws/

Comment: I have the same exact problem no one answers how to stop that forwarding and show normal error!

Comment: Getting the same issue with ClearDB. (They don't warn you when you're about to hit the limit AND there's no way to check for yourself.) On a related note, this might help (but does not work with ClearDB): https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31300/48845

Comment: I configured postgres connection for my wordpress application.

Answer (score 0):

You may install WordPress for postgres. I am the maintainer of the project.

The repository here: https://github.com/php4dev/heroku-wordpress

Comment: And ClearDB has a higher free tier if you access it as Postgres not MySQL?